# excel vs awk (delimiters)

Tags: awk, libreoffice

I have question. 
If I open a tsv file in libre office (linux excel), I have every tab delimited string in each column. But if I use awk, I received only first part of string which are delimited by space.

F.E.:
Libre office:

```
a     how much I need    0   b
b     0    0     a
c     0    15     c
d     It is really wierd  0  d
```

And If I use :

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $2}' tsv_file

how
0
0
It
```

But I would like to recieve

```
how much I need
0
0
It is really wierd
```

All fields are filled by strings and numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-F'\t'` to tell `awk` that the input is tab-delimited.  It will set `FS` to a tab.  The `OFS` variable is the *output* field delimiter/separator.

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{ print $2 }' tsv_file
```